# Repeated Measures Anova with double execution

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss

I have a similar questions to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115135/repeated-measures-anova-with-replicated-measurements), where I believe the answer has misunderstood the question (although accepted as answer).

Basically what I have is a study, which I am trying to analyze with SPSS, that has

- 2 independent variables: feedback type (A, B) and difficulty (E, H)
- 1 dependent variable: reaction time

**In all cases (AE, AH, BE, BH) tasks have been executed twice** (by each subject...within-subjects design) and thus there exist two measurements which are supposed to "strengthen" my data. I.e. dataset looks similar to the following:

```
ParticipantId,  AE_1, AE_2, AH_1, AH_2, BE_1, BE_2, BH_1, BH_2
```

I was intending to use ANOVA but am a bit unsure about assumed "repeated measures" means the same type of tasks is executed in several variations. While this is partly true for my experiment too, my data includes the repetition of a every single variation too.

I hope you can help me with this matter or point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run repeated measures ANOVA on your dataset, but (if I understood you correctly), this wouldn't give you answers for your questions.

p>0.05 in repeted measures ANOVA means that repetitions do not differ. In your case this means that `AE_1`, `AE_2`, `AH_1`, `AH_2`, `BE_1`, `BE_2`, `BH_1` and `BH_2` do not differ. p<0.05 means that there are some differences between them.

Again, if I understood you correctly, it is not what you are looking for.

If you wish to find out if feedback type and difficulty affect reaction time, you could use linear mixed models with feedback time and difficulty (and maybe their interaction) as fixed effects and participantID as random effect.

I'm not a SPSS user, so I can't tell you how to do it in SPSS, but I'm sure there exist some tutorials in the Web.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. Now I just need to find out how to prepare my data for SPSS to do so.... Thanks though, I guess I can google for that one ;)

Comment: Sadly I could not find a way to do  this in SPSS, maybe someone reading this can help me out: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299050/same-condition-repetition-within-subjects-repeated-measures-glm-in-spss